# Using python for system command

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I have to run the following simple system command from a python script.

```
python wkhtmltopdf a.html b.pdf
```

I wrote :

```
import subprocess
commands_to_run  = ['python' 'wkhtmltopdf ','a.html', 'b.pdf']
subprocess.call(commands_to_run)
```

But it gives error:

```
2014-04-08 14:12:51,530 ERROR Exception in converting html to pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloodon/site/smamodule/views.py", line 28, in convert2pdf
    subprocess.call(commands_to_run)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1201, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can some explain what am I doing wrong. And also throw a bit light on the subprocess module?

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma:

```
commands_to_run  = ['python', 'wkhtmltopdf', 'a.html', 'b.pdf']
                            ^
```

Without comma `'python' 'wkhtmltopdf'` is same as `'pythonwkhtmltopdf'` ([String literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)):

```
>>> 'python' 'wkhtmltopdf'
'pythonwkhtmltopdf'
```

**UPDATE**

Remove the space after the second command line argument.

Comment: The extra space in the second element may or may not also be a problem.

Comment: @Wooble, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: You what a naive mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share 2 ways to make the calling easier.

1) Call with a string of command and "shell=True" so that you don't have to split the command. For example,

```
subprocess.call("python wkhtmltopdf a.html b.pdf", shell=True)
```

2) If security is a concern with "shell=True" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) you can try the shlex module in standard library. For example,

```
import shlex
command = "python wkhtmltopdf a.html b.pdf"
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

shlex is especially helpful when your command is complicated.